# List directory tree structure in python?

Tags: python, traversal, directory-structure

I know that we can use `os.walk()` to list all sub-directories or all files in a directory. However, I would like to list the full directory tree content:

```
- Subdirectory 1:
   - file11
   - file12
   - Sub-sub-directory 11:
         - file111
         - file112
- Subdirectory 2:
    - file21
    - sub-sub-directory 21
    - sub-sub-directory 22    
        - sub-sub-sub-directory 221
            - file 2211
```

How to best achieve this in Python?

Answer (score 231, accepted):

Here's a function to do that with formatting:

```
import os

def list_files(startpath):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(startpath):
        level = root.replace(startpath, '').count(os.sep)
        indent = ' ' * 4 * (level)
        print('{}{}/'.format(indent, os.path.basename(root)))
        subindent = ' ' * 4 * (level + 1)
        for f in files:
            print('{}{}'.format(subindent, f))
```

Comment: This worked very well, thank you.  Though most would know, still for the benefit of newcomers into python - please note that you would need to call the function at the end (assuming windows), so you might add a new line at the end with the content list_files ("D:\\")

Comment: Worked well on python3. But on python2 `ValueError: zero length field name in format` gets thrown.

Comment: If startpath is repeated within root, won't it replace each occurrence? Changing to `root.replace(startpath, '', 1)` should fix that

Comment: It also has an issue if you use `'/'` as startpath (i.e. the root dir on a *nix system)... maybe better to just count the number of separators in `root` and subtract one to get the level: `level = root.count(os.sep) - 1`

Answer (score 85):

> ### List directory tree structure in Python?

We usually prefer to just use GNU tree, but we don't always have `tree` on every system, and sometimes Python 3 is available. A good answer here could be easily copy-pasted and not make GNU `tree` a requirement.

`tree`'s output looks like this:

```bash
$ tree
.
├── package
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __main__.py
│   ├── subpackage
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __main__.py
│   │   └── module.py
│   └── subpackage2
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── __main__.py
│       └── module2.py
└── package2
    └── __init__.py

4 directories, 9 files
```

I created the above directory structure in my home directory under a directory I call `pyscratch`.

I also see other answers here that approach that sort of output, but I think we can do better, with simpler, more modern code and lazily evaluating approaches.

### Tree in Python

To begin with, let's use an example that

- uses the Python 3 `Path` object
- uses the `yield` and `yield from` expressions (that create a generator function)
- uses recursion for elegant simplicity
- uses comments and some type annotations for extra clarity

```py
from pathlib import Path

# prefix components:
space =  '    '
branch = '│   '
# pointers:
tee =    '├── '
last =   '└── '


def tree(dir_path: Path, prefix: str=''):
    """A recursive generator, given a directory Path object
    will yield a visual tree structure line by line
    with each line prefixed by the same characters
    """    
    contents = list(dir_path.iterdir())
    # contents each get pointers that are ├── with a final └── :
    pointers = [tee] * (len(contents) - 1) + [last]
    for pointer, path in zip(pointers, contents):
        yield prefix + pointer + path.name
        if path.is_dir(): # extend the prefix and recurse:
            extension = branch if pointer == tee else space 
            # i.e. space because last, └── , above so no more |
            yield from tree(path, prefix=prefix+extension)
```

and now:

```py
for line in tree(Path.home() / 'pyscratch'):
    print(line)
```

prints:

```
├── package
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __main__.py
│   ├── subpackage
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __main__.py
│   │   └── module.py
│   └── subpackage2
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── __main__.py
│       └── module2.py
└── package2
    └── __init__.py
```

We do need to materialize each directory into a list because we need to know how long it is, but afterwards we throw the list away. For deep and broad recursion this should be lazy enough.

The above code, with the comments, should be sufficient to fully understand what we're doing here, but feel free to step through it with a debugger to better grock it if you need to.

### More features

Now GNU `tree` gives us a couple of useful features that I'd like to have with this function:

- prints the subject directory name first (does so automatically, ours does not)
- prints the count of `n directories, m files`
- option to limit recursion, `-L level`
- option to limit to just directories, `-d`

Also, when there is a huge tree, it is useful to limit the iteration (e.g. with `islice`) to avoid locking up your interpreter with text, as at some point the output becomes too verbose to be useful. We can make this arbitrarily high by default - say `1000`.

So let's remove the previous comments and fill out this functionality:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from itertools import islice

space =  '    '
branch = '│   '
tee =    '├── '
last =   '└── '
```

```py
def tree(dir_path: Path, level: int=-1, limit_to_directories: bool=False,
         length_limit: int=1000):
    """Given a directory Path object print a visual tree structure"""
    dir_path = Path(dir_path) # accept string coerceable to Path
    files = 0
    directories = 0
    def inner(dir_path: Path, prefix: str='', level=-1):
        nonlocal files, directories
        if not level: 
            return # 0, stop iterating
        if limit_to_directories:
            contents = [d for d in dir_path.iterdir() if d.is_dir()]
        else: 
            contents = list(dir_path.iterdir())
        pointers = [tee] * (len(contents) - 1) + [last]
        for pointer, path in zip(pointers, contents):
            if path.is_dir():
                yield prefix + pointer + path.name
                directories += 1
                extension = branch if pointer == tee else space 
                yield from inner(path, prefix=prefix+extension, level=level-1)
            elif not limit_to_directories:
                yield prefix + pointer + path.name
                files += 1
    print(dir_path.name)
    iterator = inner(dir_path, level=level)
    for line in islice(iterator, length_limit):
        print(line)
    if next(iterator, None):
        print(f'... length_limit, {length_limit}, reached, counted:')
    print(f'\n{directories} directories' + (f', {files} files' if files else ''))
```

And now we can get the same sort of output as `tree`:

```py
tree(Path.home() / 'pyscratch')
```

prints:

```
pyscratch
├── package
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __main__.py
│   ├── subpackage
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __main__.py
│   │   └── module.py
│   └── subpackage2
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── __main__.py
│       └── module2.py
└── package2
    └── __init__.py

4 directories, 9 files
```

And we can restrict to levels:

```py
tree(Path.home() / 'pyscratch', level=2)
```

prints:

```
pyscratch
├── package
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __main__.py
│   ├── subpackage
│   └── subpackage2
└── package2
    └── __init__.py

4 directories, 3 files
```

And we can limit the output to directories:

```py
tree(Path.home() / 'pyscratch', level=2, limit_to_directories=True)
```

prints:

```
pyscratch
├── package
│   ├── subpackage
│   └── subpackage2
└── package2

4 directories
```

### Retrospective

In retrospect, we could have used `path.glob` for matching. We could also perhaps use `path.rglob` for recursive globbing, but that would require a rewrite. We could also use `itertools.tee` instead of materializing a list of directory contents, but that could have negative tradeoffs and would probably make the code even more complex.

Comments are welcome!

Comment: To also print the lines-of-code, after `elif not limit_to_directories:` add the following: ```info = prefix + pointer + path.name; try: with path.open('r') as f: n_lines = len(f.readlines()); loc = f'  LOC: {n_lines}'; info += loc; except UnicodeDecodeError: pass; yield info```  See [this link](https://github.com/StevenCHowell/dev-journal/blob/master/journal.md#tuesday-7-jan-2020) for proper white-space.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed in my code, and taught me some new Python tricks! Only thing I'd note is that `contents` needs to be filtered if `limit_to_directories` is True. Otherwise if a folder doesn't have a directory for the last file, the tree won't be drawn correctly.
`if limit_to_directories: contents = [path for path in contents if path.is_dir()]`

Comment: @hennign thanks, answer updated, appreciate the feedback!

Comment: Python is all predicated on `list(dir_path.iterdir())` returning a properly ordered top-down tree of directory structure. I see *no such guarantee* in the [API for iterdir()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.iterdir). Please provide a reference on how `iterdir()` orders or is guaranteed to provide the desired ordering.

Comment: @ingyhere I'm not sure where you got that idea - it [seems to use `os.listdir()` by default](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/pathlib.py#L405) - [which makes no guarantee of the order](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) : "The list is in arbitrary order, and does not include the special entries '.' and '..' even if they are present in the directory."

Comment: @AaronHall The question references `os.walk()`, which [does guarantee a top-down order](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk). Code above is using Pathlib's `iterdir()` which doesn't guarantee the same. That's my point. Maybe we agree? Top-down is important for things like `rmdir()` which can only delete empty dirs in order (can't remove a dir with items in it). The `os.walk()` API has been around for awhile and is very tested. I think it is hard to duplicate that kind of tried-and-true method.

Comment: @ingyhere the top-down behavior in this visitor is hard-coded. This code is purely intended to draw the tree-like structure. You should not modify this to remove files. I would prefer you use [`shutil.rmtree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree) for such a purpose.

Comment: GNU `tree` does not show/traverse hidden files/directories by default. Maybe we should mimic the same behavior?

Answer (score 84):

Similar to answers above, but for python3, arguably readable and arguably extensible:

```
from pathlib import Path

class DisplayablePath(object):
    display_filename_prefix_middle = '├──'
    display_filename_prefix_last = '└──'
    display_parent_prefix_middle = '    '
    display_parent_prefix_last = '│   '

    def __init__(self, path, parent_path, is_last):
        self.path = Path(str(path))
        self.parent = parent_path
        self.is_last = is_last
        if self.parent:
            self.depth = self.parent.depth + 1
        else:
            self.depth = 0

    @property
    def displayname(self):
        if self.path.is_dir():
            return self.path.name + '/'
        return self.path.name

    @classmethod
    def make_tree(cls, root, parent=None, is_last=False, criteria=None):
        root = Path(str(root))
        criteria = criteria or cls._default_criteria

        displayable_root = cls(root, parent, is_last)
        yield displayable_root

        children = sorted(list(path
                               for path in root.iterdir()
                               if criteria(path)),
                          key=lambda s: str(s).lower())
        count = 1
        for path in children:
            is_last = count == len(children)
            if path.is_dir():
                yield from cls.make_tree(path,
                                         parent=displayable_root,
                                         is_last=is_last,
                                         criteria=criteria)
            else:
                yield cls(path, displayable_root, is_last)
            count += 1

    @classmethod
    def _default_criteria(cls, path):
        return True

    @property
    def displayname(self):
        if self.path.is_dir():
            return self.path.name + '/'
        return self.path.name

    def displayable(self):
        if self.parent is None:
            return self.displayname

        _filename_prefix = (self.display_filename_prefix_last
                            if self.is_last
                            else self.display_filename_prefix_middle)

        parts = ['{!s} {!s}'.format(_filename_prefix,
                                    self.displayname)]

        parent = self.parent
        while parent and parent.parent is not None:
            parts.append(self.display_parent_prefix_middle
                         if parent.is_last
                         else self.display_parent_prefix_last)
            parent = parent.parent

        return ''.join(reversed(parts))
```

Example usage:

```
paths = DisplayablePath.make_tree(
    Path('doc'),
    criteria=is_not_hidden
)
for path in paths:
    print(path.displayable())

# With a criteria (skip hidden files)
def is_not_hidden(path):
    return not path.name.startswith(".")

paths = DisplayablePath.make_tree(Path('doc'), criteria=is_not_hidden)
for path in paths:
    print(path.displayable())
```

Example output:

```
doc/
├── _static/
│   ├── embedded/
│   │   ├── deep_file
│   │   └── very/
│   │       └── deep/
│   │           └── folder/
│   │               └── very_deep_file
│   └── less_deep_file
├── about.rst
├── conf.py
└── index.rst
```

#### Notes

- This uses recursion. It will raise a [RecursionError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#RecursionError) on really **deep** folder trees
- The tree is lazily evaluated.  It should behave well on really **wide** folder trees.  Immediate children of a given folder are not lazily evaluated, though.

#### Edit:

- Added bonus! criteria callback for filtering paths.

Comment: Nice tool, do you have a quick example on how to use criteria in order to exclude folder names?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: `DisplayablePath.make_tree(Path('doc'), criteria=lambda path: True if path.name not in ('.git',  '__pycache__') else False))` Is an example of filtering out unwanted paths.

Comment: @Matt-Mac-Muffin I have added a criteria example

Comment: I'm missing something here.  What is the is_not_hidden?

Comment: @braintho I've edited the example usage to show the use of `is_not_hidden` as the `criteria` argument.

Comment: Code requires some adjustments. (1) `displayname` method appears twice. (2) `is_not_hidden` is referenced before it is defined. 
Even after making these adjustments, the code didn't work as expected: printed a lot of `None`s and the name of the top directory twice. (I'm on Windows)

Answer (score 38):

I created a package called [seedir](https://github.com/earnestt1234/seedir) for doing this and other things with folder tree diagrams:

```
>>> import seedir as sd
>>> sd.seedir('/path/to/package', style='emoji')
 package/
├─ __init__.py
├─ subpackage1/
│ ├─ __init__.py
│ ├─ moduleX.py
│ └─ moduleY.py
├─ subpackage2/
│ ├─ __init__.py
│ └─ moduleZ.py
└─ moduleA.py
```

Something similar to the style OP used can be done with:

```
>>> sd.seedir('/path/to/package', style='spaces', indent=4, anystart='- ')
- package/
    - __init__.py
    - subpackage1/
        - __init__.py
        - moduleX.py
        - moduleY.py
    - subpackage2/
        - __init__.py
        - moduleZ.py
    - moduleA.py
```

---

There is also a command-line interface. For example:

```
seedir -y emoji
```

For all the options, see

```
seedir --help
```

You can also do `python -m seedir`.

Comment: Is it possible to export to .png image?

Comment: @israteneda currently no, but could be added!

Comment: @Justaus3r yes!

Comment: This is the only reasonable answer. For the others, it's preferable a nice mature package instead of an uncooked recipe in the answers, also, the question is python, not gnu, not bash, no other languages. So, thanks for this one, seedir

Answer (score 31):

A solution without your indentation:

```
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(given_path):
  print path
  for f in files:
    print f
```

os.walk already does the top-down, depth-first walk you are looking for.

Ignoring the dirs list prevents the overlapping you mention.

Comment: python says: `NameError: name 'path' is not defined`

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani "path" is the variable containing the directory you want to print, i.e. r"C:\Users\username\Documents\path"

Answer (score 19):

I came here looking for the same thing and used dhobbs answer for me. As a way of thanking the community, I added some arguments to write to a file, as akshay asked, and made showing files optional so it is not so bit an output. Also made the indentation an optional argument so you can change it, as some like it to be 2 and others prefer 4.

Used different loops so the one not showing files doesn't check if it has to on each iteration.

Hope it helps someone else as dhobbs answer helped me. Thanks a lot.

```
def showFolderTree(path,show_files=False,indentation=2,file_output=False):
    """
    Shows the content of a folder in a tree structure.
    path -(string)- path of the root folder we want to show.
    show_files -(boolean)-  Whether or not we want to see files listed.
                            Defaults to False.
    indentation -(int)- Indentation we want to use, defaults to 2.   
    file_output -(string)-  Path (including the name) of the file where we want
                            to save the tree.
    """

       
    tree = []

    if not show_files:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            level = root.replace(path, '').count(os.sep)
            indent = ' '*indentation*(level)
            tree.append('{}{}/'.format(indent,os.path.basename(root)))
            
    if show_files:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            level = root.replace(path, '').count(os.sep)
            indent = ' '*indentation*(level)
            tree.append('{}{}/'.format(indent,os.path.basename(root)))    
            for f in files:
                subindent=' ' * indentation * (level+1)
                tree.append('{}{}'.format(subindent,f))
            
    if file_output:
        output_file = open(file_output,'w')
        for line in tree:
            output_file.write(line)
            output_file.write('\n')
    else:
        # Default behaviour: print on screen.
        for line in tree:
            print line
```

Comment: I feel this answer doesn't contribute to the already accepted answer. The only thing you are providing is additional fluff code to turn off features or not in the response.

Comment: Your feeling is right, @jason-heine. The accepted answer is good enough, but some people asked how to do this fluff stuff and I wanted to give something to them. Downvote it or report my answer if you don't want to see this in SO, I thought it wouldn't hurt, but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 10):

Based on this fantastic post

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/217212-treepy-graphically-displays-the-directory-structur/

Here es a refinement to behave exactly like

http://linux.die.net/man/1/tree

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# tree.py
#
# Written by Doug Dahms
#
# Prints the tree structure for the path specified on the command line

from os import listdir, sep
from os.path import abspath, basename, isdir
from sys import argv

def tree(dir, padding, print_files=False, isLast=False, isFirst=False):
    if isFirst:
        print padding.decode('utf8')[:-1].encode('utf8') + dir
    else:
        if isLast:
            print padding.decode('utf8')[:-1].encode('utf8') + '└── ' + basename(abspath(dir))
        else:
            print padding.decode('utf8')[:-1].encode('utf8') + '├── ' + basename(abspath(dir))
    files = []
    if print_files:
        files = listdir(dir)
    else:
        files = [x for x in listdir(dir) if isdir(dir + sep + x)]
    if not isFirst:
        padding = padding + '   '
    files = sorted(files, key=lambda s: s.lower())
    count = 0
    last = len(files) - 1
    for i, file in enumerate(files):
        count += 1
        path = dir + sep + file
        isLast = i == last
        if isdir(path):
            if count == len(files):
                if isFirst:
                    tree(path, padding, print_files, isLast, False)
                else:
                    tree(path, padding + ' ', print_files, isLast, False)
            else:
                tree(path, padding + '│', print_files, isLast, False)
        else:
            if isLast:
                print padding + '└── ' + file
            else:
                print padding + '├── ' + file

def usage():
    return '''Usage: %s [-f] 
Print tree structure of path specified.
Options:
-f      Print files as well as directories
PATH    Path to process''' % basename(argv[0])

def main():
    if len(argv) == 1:
        print usage()
    elif len(argv) == 2:
        # print just directories
        path = argv[1]
        if isdir(path):
            tree(path, '', False, False, True)
        else:
            print 'ERROR: \'' + path + '\' is not a directory'
    elif len(argv) == 3 and argv[1] == '-f':
        # print directories and files
        path = argv[2]
        if isdir(path):
            tree(path, '', True, False, True)
        else:
            print 'ERROR: \'' + path + '\' is not a directory'
    else:
        print usage()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 9):

```
import os

def fs_tree_to_dict(path_):
    file_token = ''
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path_):
        tree = {d: fs_tree_to_dict(os.path.join(root, d)) for d in dirs}
        tree.update({f: file_token for f in files})
        return tree  # note we discontinue iteration trough os.walk
```

If anybody is interested - that recursive function returns nested structure of dictionaries. Keys are `file system` names (of directories and files), values are either:

- sub dictionaries for directories
- strings for files (see `file_token`)

The strings designating files are empty in this example. They can also be e.g. given file contents or its owner info or privileges or whatever object different than a dict. Unless it's a dictionary it can be easily distinguished from a "directory type" in further operations.

Having such a tree in a filesystem:

```
# bash:
$ tree /tmp/ex
/tmp/ex
├── d_a
│   ├── d_a_a
│   ├── d_a_b
│   │   └── f1.txt
│   ├── d_a_c
│   └── fa.txt
├── d_b
│   ├── fb1.txt
│   └── fb2.txt
└── d_c
```

The result will be:

```
# python 2 or 3:
>>> fs_tree_to_dict("/tmp/ex")
{
    'd_a': {
        'd_a_a': {},
        'd_a_b': {
            'f1.txt': ''
        },
        'd_a_c': {},
        'fa.txt': ''
    },
    'd_b': {
        'fb1.txt': '',
        'fb2.txt': ''
    },
    'd_c': {}
}
```

If you like that, I've already created a package (python 2 & 3) with this stuff (and a nice `pyfakefs` helper):
https://pypi.org/project/fsforge/

Comment: could you please elaborate on how `file_token` could be used to read file properties, such as, for example filesize , thanks!

Comment: Sure. Change the line `tree.update({f: file_token for f in files})` into `tree.update({f: os.path.getsize(os.path.join(root, f)) for f in files})`. The line defining `file_token` can be removed then.

Answer (score 5):

On top of dhobbs answer above (https://stackoverflow.com/a/9728478/624597), here is an extra functionality of storing results to a file (I personally use it to copy and paste to [FreeMind](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) to have a nice overview of the structure, therefore I used tabs instead of spaces for indentation):

```
import os

def list_files(startpath):

    with open("folder_structure.txt", "w") as f_output:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(startpath):
            level = root.replace(startpath, '').count(os.sep)
            indent = '\t' * 1 * (level)
            output_string = '{}{}/'.format(indent, os.path.basename(root))
            print(output_string)
            f_output.write(output_string + '\n')
            subindent = '\t' * 1 * (level + 1)
            for f in files:
                output_string = '{}{}'.format(subindent, f)
                print(output_string)
                f_output.write(output_string + '\n')

list_files(".")
```

Answer (score 4):

This solution will only work if you have `tree` installed on your system.  However I'm leaving this solution here just in case it helps someone else out.

You can tell tree to output the tree structure as XML (`tree -X`) or JSON (`tree -J`).  JSON of course can be parsed directly with python and XML can easily be read with `lxml`.

With the following directory structure as an example:

```
[sri@localhost Projects]$ tree --charset=ascii bands
bands
|-- DreamTroll
|   |-- MattBaldwinson
|   |-- members.txt
|   |-- PaulCarter
|   |-- SimonBlakelock
|   `-- Rob Stringer
|-- KingsX
|   |-- DougPinnick
|   |-- JerryGaskill
|   |-- members.txt
|   `-- TyTabor
|-- Megadeth
|   |-- DaveMustaine
|   |-- DavidEllefson
|   |-- DirkVerbeuren
|   |-- KikoLoureiro
|   `-- members.txt
|-- Nightwish
|   |-- EmppuVuorinen
|   |-- FloorJansen
|   |-- JukkaNevalainen
|   |-- MarcoHietala
|   |-- members.txt
|   |-- TroyDonockley
|   `-- TuomasHolopainen
`-- Rush
    |-- AlexLifeson
    |-- GeddyLee
    `-- NeilPeart

5 directories, 25 files
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tree>
  <directory name="bands">
    <directory name="DreamTroll">
      <file name="MattBaldwinson"></file>
      <file name="members.txt"></file>
      <file name="PaulCarter"></file>
      <file name="RobStringer"></file>
      <file name="SimonBlakelock"></file>
    </directory>
    <directory name="KingsX">
      <file name="DougPinnick"></file>
      <file name="JerryGaskill"></file>
      <file name="members.txt"></file>
      <file name="TyTabor"></file>
    </directory>
    <directory name="Megadeth">
      <file name="DaveMustaine"></file>
      <file name="DavidEllefson"></file>
      <file name="DirkVerbeuren"></file>
      <file name="KikoLoureiro"></file>
      <file name="members.txt"></file>
    </directory>
    <directory name="Nightwish">
      <file name="EmppuVuorinen"></file>
      <file name="FloorJansen"></file>
      <file name="JukkaNevalainen"></file>
      <file name="MarcoHietala"></file>
      <file name="members.txt"></file>
      <file name="TroyDonockley"></file>
      <file name="TuomasHolopainen"></file>
    </directory>
    <directory name="Rush">
      <file name="AlexLifeson"></file>
      <file name="GeddyLee"></file>
      <file name="NeilPeart"></file>
    </directory>
  </directory>
  <report>
    <directories>5</directories>
    <files>25</files>
  </report>
</tree>
```

**JSON**

```
[sri@localhost Projects]$ tree -J bands
[
  {"type":"directory","name":"bands","contents":[
    {"type":"directory","name":"DreamTroll","contents":[
      {"type":"file","name":"MattBaldwinson"},
      {"type":"file","name":"members.txt"},
      {"type":"file","name":"PaulCarter"},
      {"type":"file","name":"RobStringer"},
      {"type":"file","name":"SimonBlakelock"}
    ]},
    {"type":"directory","name":"KingsX","contents":[
      {"type":"file","name":"DougPinnick"},
      {"type":"file","name":"JerryGaskill"},
      {"type":"file","name":"members.txt"},
      {"type":"file","name":"TyTabor"}
    ]},
    {"type":"directory","name":"Megadeth","contents":[
      {"type":"file","name":"DaveMustaine"},
      {"type":"file","name":"DavidEllefson"},
      {"type":"file","name":"DirkVerbeuren"},
      {"type":"file","name":"KikoLoureiro"},
      {"type":"file","name":"members.txt"}
    ]},
    {"type":"directory","name":"Nightwish","contents":[
      {"type":"file","name":"EmppuVuorinen"},
      {"type":"file","name":"FloorJansen"},
      {"type":"file","name":"JukkaNevalainen"},
      {"type":"file","name":"MarcoHietala"},
      {"type":"file","name":"members.txt"},
      {"type":"file","name":"TroyDonockley"},
      {"type":"file","name":"TuomasHolopainen"}
    ]},
    {"type":"directory","name":"Rush","contents":[
      {"type":"file","name":"AlexLifeson"},
      {"type":"file","name":"GeddyLee"},
      {"type":"file","name":"NeilPeart"}
    ]}
  ]},
  {"type":"report","directories":5,"files":25}
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can execute 'tree' command of Linux shell.

Installation:

```
   ~$sudo apt install tree
```

Using in python

```
    >>> import os
    >>> os.system('tree <desired path>')
```

Example:

```
    >>> os.system('tree ~/Desktop/myproject')
```

This gives you a cleaner structure and is visually more comprehensive and easy to type.

Comment: This is not very portable solution as this fails on Windows + relies on additional program

Comment: @oglop, tree is a standard dos command. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DOS_commands#TREE

Answer (score 2):

Most minimal native solution:

```py
from pathlib import Path

def print_tree(path, prefix=''):
    for item in path.iterdir():
        print(f'{prefix}├── {item.name}')
        if item.is_dir():
            print_tree(item, prefix + '│   ')
```

Output:

```py
curr_dir = Path(__file__).resolve().parent
print_tree(curr_dir)

├── aaa
│   ├── a.txt
│   ├── a1
│   ├── a2
├── bbb
│   ├── b.txt
├── tree.py
```

You can modify it to optionally show only directories:

```py
def print_tree(path, prefix='', show_files=False):
    for item in path.iterdir():
        if item.is_dir():
            print(f'{prefix}├── {item.name}/')
            print_tree(item, prefix + '│   ', show_files)
        elif show_files:
            print(f'{prefix}├── {item.name}')
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe faster than @ellockie ( Maybe )

```
import os
def file_writer(text):
    with open("folder_structure.txt","a") as f_output:
        f_output.write(text)
def list_files(startpath):


    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(startpath):
        level = root.replace(startpath, '').count(os.sep)
        indent = '\t' * 1 * (level)
        output_string = '{}{}/ \n'.format(indent, os.path.basename(root))
        file_writer(output_string)
        subindent = '\t' * 1 * (level + 1)
        output_string = '%s %s \n' %(subindent,[f for f in files])
        file_writer(''.join(output_string))


list_files("/")
```

Test results in screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Python2 & Python3:
I saw several answers on here that are much more conscience than my own, however, for my applications, I did not have access to the libraries they relied on. This was my solution to the task. Also, for my application, I needed to know the absolute path for each file so I printed it out along with the file name.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf_8 -*-
import os

PIPE = "│"
ELBOW = "└──"
TEE = "├──"
PIPE_PREFIX = "│   "
SPACE_PREFIX = "    "


def list_files(startpath):

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(startpath):
        break
    
    tree = []    
    for i, file in enumerate(files):
        if i == len(files)-1 and len(dirs) == 0:
            joint = ELBOW
        else:
            joint = TEE
        tree.append('{} {} : {}'.format(joint, file, os.path.join(root, file)))
    
    for i, dir in enumerate(dirs):
        if i == len(dirs)-1:
            joint = ELBOW
            space = SPACE_PREFIX
        else:
            joint = TEE
            space = PIPE_PREFIX
        
        tree.append('{} {}/'.format(joint, dir))
        branches = list_files(os.path.join(root,dir))
       for branch in branches:
            tree.append('{}{}'.format(space, branch))

    return tree

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Obtain top level directory path
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    tree = list_files(cwd)   
    
    string = '../{}/\n'.format(os.path.basename(cwd))
    for t in tree:
        string += '{}\n'.format(t)
    string = string.replace('\n', '\n   ')
    print(string)
```

The output of the script is:

```
../TEST_DIR/
├── test.txt : /usr/scripts/TEST_DIR/test.txt
├── a/
│   ├── 1.txt : /usr/scripts/TEST_DIR/a/1.txt
│   ├── 2.py : /usr/scripts/TEST_DIR/a/2.py
│   └── 3.bit : /usr/scripts/TEST_DIR/a/3.bit
├── b/
│   ├── bb/
│   │   ├── 1.txt : /usr/scripts/TEST_DIR/b/bb/1.txt
│   │   ├── 2.py : /usr/scripts/TEST_DIR/b/bb/2.py
│   │   ├── 3.bit : /usr/scripts/TEST_DIR/b/bb/3.bit
│   │   └── bb_copy/
│   │       ├── 1.txt : /usr/scripts/TEST_DIR/b/bb/bb_copy/1.txt
│   │       ├── 2.py : /usr/scripts/TEST_DIR/b/bb/bb_copy/2.py
│   │       ├── 3.bit : /usr/scripts/TEST_DIR/b/bb/bb_copy/3.bit
│   │       └── bb_copy/
│   │           ├── 1.txt : /usr/scripts/TEST_DIR/b/bb/bb_copy/bb_copy/1.txt
│   │           ├── 2.py : /usr/scripts/TEST_DIR/b/bb/bb_copy/bb_copy/2.py
│   │           └── 3.bit : /usr/scripts/TEST_DIR/b/bb/bb_copy/bb_copy/3.bit
│   └── bb_copy/
│       ├── 1.txt : /usr/scripts/TEST_DIR/b/bb_copy/1.txt
│       ├── 2.py : /usr/scripts/TEST_DIR/b/bb_copy/2.py
│       └── 3.bit : /usr/scripts/TEST_DIR/b/bb_copy/3.bit
└── c/
```

I would appreciate any tips for making this script more streamline, conscience, and robust. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find code with output like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56622847/6671330

```
V .
|-> V folder1
|   |-> V folder2
|   |   |-> V folder3
|   |   |   |-> file3.txt
|   |   |-> file2.txt
|   |-> V folderX
|   |-> file1.txt
|-> 02-hw1_wdwwfm.py
|-> 06-t1-home1.py
|-> 06-t1-home2.py
|-> hw1.py
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still looking for an answer. Here is a recursive approach to get the paths in a dictionary.

```
import os


def list_files(startpath):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(startpath):
        dir_content = []
        for dir in dirs:
            go_inside = os.path.join(startpath, dir)
            dir_content.append(list_files(go_inside))
        files_lst = []
        for f in files:
            files_lst.append(f)
        return {'name': root, 'files': files_lst, 'dirs': dir_content}
```

Answer (score 0):

[@dhobbs's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9728478/6494418) is great!

but simply change to easy get the level info

```py
def print_list_dir(dir):
    print("=" * 64)
    print("[PRINT LIST DIR] %s" % dir)
    print("=" * 64)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
        level = root.replace(dir, '').count(os.sep)
        indent = '| ' * level
        print('{}{} \\'.format(indent, os.path.basename(root)))
        subindent = '| ' * (level + 1)
        for f in files:
            print('{}{}'.format(subindent, f))
    print("=" * 64)
```

and the output like

```py
================================================================
[PRINT LIST DIR] ./
================================================================
 \
| os_name.py
| json_loads.py
| linspace_python.py
| list_file.py
| to_gson_format.py
| type_convert_test.py
| in_and_replace_test.py
| online_log.py
| padding_and_clipping.py
| str_tuple.py
| set_test.py
| script_name.py
| word_count.py
| get14.py
| np_test2.py
================================================================
```

you can get the level by `|` count!

Answer (score 0):

Just another `tree()` function, with some features I find useful:

- Set `max_files` to limit the number of files per directory
- Set `max_level` to limit the depth
- Set `sort_by` to sort the files and directories, for example `sort_by=os.path.getmtime` to sort by last-modified date. Default is to sort by name. Note that directories are always shown before files.
- Set `indent` to set the number of spaces per indent level, default to 4.

```py
from pathlib import Path

def tree(path, *, indent=4, max_files=None, sort_by=None, level=0, max_level=None):
    path = Path(path)
    if not path.is_dir():
        return
    indent_str = " " * indent * level
    print(f"{indent_str}{path.name}/")
    sub_indent_str = " " * indent * (level + 1)
    dir_content = list(path.iterdir())
    subdirs = [filepath for filepath in dir_content if filepath.is_dir()]
    files = [filepath for filepath in dir_content if not filepath in subdirs]
    if max_level is not None and level < max_level:
        for subdir in sorted(subdirs, key=sort_by):
            tree(subdir, indent=indent, max_files=max_files, sort_by=sort_by,
                 level=level + 1, max_level=max_level)
    for idx, filepath in enumerate(sorted(files, key=sort_by)):
        if max_files is not None and idx >= max_files:
            print(f"{sub_indent_str}...")
            break
        print(f"{sub_indent_str}{filepath.name}")
```

Example output:

```
some_path/
    some_subdir/
    another_subdir/
        foo.txt
        bar.txt
    big_subdir/
        a00001.txt
        a00002.txt
        a00003.txt
        ...
    deeply_nested/
        max_depth1/
        max_depth2/
```