# Distinguish between a file or a directory in paramiko

Tags: python, file, attributes, mode, paramiko

I'm trying to walk over the contents of a directory and determine whether or not each item is a file or a folder. I can do the solution suggested in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12295551):

```
>>> for i in ftp.listdir():
...     lstatout=str(ftp.lstat(i)).split()[0]
...     if 'd' not in lstatout: print i, 'is a file'
...
```

This works, yes. As a sidenote, I'm just taking the first character instead of `.split()`, so `str(ftp.lstati(i))[0] != 'd'`, as this appears to be faster in my admittedly non-scientific testing.

But this seems extremely hacky, so I tried to check out other methods. In the SFTP attributes for a few folders, I see:

```
<SFTPAttributes: [ size=4096 uid=1002 gid=1002 mode=040755 atime=1358785383 mtime=1359475285 ]>
```

while in the same for files, I see:

```
<SFTPAttributes: [ size=72 uid=1002 gid=1002 mode=0100644 atime=1367598914 mtime=1367598914 ]>
```

So it seems that the mode is `010[permissions]` for files, and `040[permissions]` for directories (consistent in the few directories I've seen, but can't say it's universal). This seems to be a much better way to get that attribute of the item! But, when I use `ftp.stat(i).st_mode`, I get a different value – `16877` for the aforementioned directory, and `33188` for the aforementioned file.

What do these mean? Is there a way I can convert that integer to the file mode? (I tried Google, but can't find anything relevant.) Alternatively, is there any good way I can determine this without relying on the `str(lstat(i))` function returning a 'd' or not-'d'?

Comment: Modes are octal.  You can do `oct(integerValue)` to see the mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the high bits do indeed tell you whether it is a file or a directory:

[S_ISDIR](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stat.html#stat.S_IFDIR)
[S_ISREG](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stat.html#stat.S_IFREG)

```
>>> oct(16877)
'040755'
>>> oct(33188)
'0100644'
```

And likewise:

```
>>> int('040755', 8)
16877
>>> int('0100644', 8)
33188
```

Answer (score 7):

Paramiko's `SFTPAttributes.st_mode` can be passed to Python's `os.stat` for analysis:

```
for file in ftp_cli.listdir_attr(path):
    is_dir = stat.S_ISDIR(file.st_mode)
    is_link = stat.S_ISLNK(file.st_mode)
    is_file = stat.S_ISREG(file.st_mode)
```

Comment: Another variation of the same thing: 
`import stat`

`is_dir = stat.S_ISDIR(ftp.stat(remotepath).st_mode)`

Answer (score 0):

Python 3

```
from paramiko.sftp_attr import SFTPAttributes
import stat

class FileInfo:
    def __init__(self, file: SFTPAttributes):
        self.name = file.filename
        self.is_dir = stat.S_ISDIR(file.st_mode)
        self.is_link = stat.S_ISLNK(file.st_mode)
        self.is_file = stat.S_ISREG(file.st_mode)
        self.size = file.st_size
        self.modified_on = file.st_mtime
```