# C/Unix: How to extract the bits from st_mode?

Tags: c, linux, file, unix, directory

I am a beginner to Unix programming and C and I have two questions regarding the `struct stat` and its field `st_mode`:

1. When accessing the `st_mode` field as below, what type of number is returned( octal, decimal, etc.) ?

   ```
   struct stat file;
   stat( someFilePath, &file);
   printf("%d", file.st_mode );
   ```

I thought the number is in octal but when I ran this code, and I got the value `33188`. What is the base ?

2. I found out that the `st_mode` encodes a 16 bit binary number that represents the file type and file permissions. How do I get the 16-bit number from the above output(esp. when it doesn't seem to be in octal). And which parts of the 16-bit digit encodes which information ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 11):

I think you are mixing concepts here.

In memory, integer values are always in binary, let's call it *native format*. `st_mode` is of type `mode_t` and that type is an unspecified integer type, probably `int`.

The concept of *base*, that is decimal, octal or hexadecimal, is useful only when you covert the number in memory in native format to a text representation, (or back from text to native).

For example:

```
int x = 42;
```

assigns the number 42 to the integer variable. Since source code is text, the `42` is input as text, and we know that it is a decimal value (no prefix). But note how we do not specify a base for the variable: it does not have one.
This other code:

```
int x = 0x2A;
```

is exactly equivalent. Instead of the decimal constant `42` it uses the hexadecimal constant `0x2A`, but that is identical, and `x` got the same value on both cases. Likewise:

```
int x = 052;
```

is also equivalent, but with an octal constant.

Now to your code. When you do:

```
printf("%d", file.st_mode);
33188
```

you tell the program to output the value of that variable as a decimal number. Remember that `printf` converts the number from native format to text, so the base of that text matters. If you prefer to see the value as octal, just write:

```
printf("%o", file.st_mode);
100644
```

Or in hexadecimal:

```
printf("%x", file.st_mode);
81A4
```

The nice thing about octal is that itrepresents exactly 3 bit per octal digit (4 bits per digit for hex.), so with a bit of practise you can see the bits without computations.

For example, your `st_mode` is `33188` in decimal or `0100644` in octal. The decimal tells me nothing, but the octal does mean something, because I remember that the last 9 bits (3 octal digits) are the permissions: 3 bits for the owner, 3 bits for the group, 3 bits for other. So:

```
* Owner: 6 that is rw-
* Group: 4 that is r--
* Other: 4 that is r--
```

BTW, the last 1 is this constant:

```
#define S_IFREG 0100000
```

that just means that it is a regular file.

Answer (score 0):

1. The number is a set to a value. In `printf()` you can either use `"%d"` to print it in decimal form (as you did), or use `"%o"` (or `"%lo"`) instead, to print it in octal form.
2. Check [man 2 stat](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) about how each information is represented. Then, you can use a bitmask to extract the information you need. There's an example demonstrating it in the man page.

Answer (score 0):

You printed it as decimal, so you got decimal.  If you'd printed it as octal, you'd have gotten octal; ditto for hex.

The `st_mode` field is most easily understood when printed as octal.

```
printf("mode = %07o\n", file.st_mode);
```

The last three digits are the familiar permissions (644, for example) for `chmod` etc.  The 4th digit from the right is usually 0 but will be non-zero for set-UID, set-GID or sticky-bit files or directories.  The remaining digits identify the type of the file.

You can use the macros from `<sys/stat.h>` to dissect the information.