# Getting all FTP directory/file listings recursively in one call

Tags: .net, ftp, fluentftp

I'm creating a backup program that backs data up to FTP. To archive effectively, I need to do several file attribute comparisons.  Right now, I am using `FluentFTP` and calling `FtpClient.FileExists` `FtpClient.GetFileSize`, and `FtpClient.GetModifiedTime` *per file*.  This is obviously not very optimal.

If I could download the FTP directory's entire tree structure in a single call along with file attributes, it would improve back-up speed substantially.  The alternative is to build a local index, but then I have to make sure it's being updated properly and also account for the possibility of it getting corrupted.

Is there any way to do this other than roll my own solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FTP offers these commands to retrieve an information about remote files:

- `NLST` to retrieve names of files in certain directory – Supported by *all* servers.
- `SIZE` and `MDTM` to retrieve size and modification file of certain file – Supported by *virtually* all servers.
- `LIST` to retrieve directory listing, including file attributes – Supported by *all* servers, but the listing is not standardized and thus not really machine-readable. Though most servers will support *nix style listing (like *nix `ls` command). Though each will have its quirks.
- `MLSD` to retrieve directory listing, including file attributes in machine readable format – This command is least supported. It's particularly not supported by *nix vsftpd and Windows IIS.

So you do not have to use `FtpClient.GetFileSize` and `FtpClient.GetModifiedTime` *per file*. Use `FtpClient.GetListing` *per directory*. Internally it uses `MLSD`, if supported by the server. Otherwise it falls back to `LIST` and tries to parse the listing.

---

Some FTP servers (like ProFTPD) do support a non-standard proprietary `-R` switch to the `LIST` command that will make them return listing across all subfolders. FluentFTP supports that too (`FtpListOption.Recursive`). Though note that FluentFTP uses `-R` with `LIST` only, while it prefers using `MLSD`, if the server supports it. So to make sure `LIST -R` is used, you need to use both `FtpListOption.Recursive` and `FtpListOption.ForceList`.

If your server does not support the `-R` switch, you have to implement recursion yourself. Or use an FTP client that has API for it.

For example with *my* [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library), you can use [`Session.EnumerateRemoteFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_enumerateremotefiles):

```
IEnumerable<RemoteFileInfo> allFiles =
    session.EnumerateRemoteFiles("/", null, EnumerationOptions.AllDirectories);
```