# Recursive file list with FTP

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I know how to list all files in a directory from a FTP server:

```
import ftplib
ftp = ftplib.FTP()
ftp.connect("192.168.1.18", port=2240)
ftp.login()
ftp.cwd('path/to')
for f in ftp.mlsd():
    print(f)
```

**But what's the best way to obtain a recursive filelist (i.e. files in subdirectories, subsubdirectories, etc.)?**

i.e. an equivalent for FTP of Python 3's `glob.glob('path/to/**/*', recursive=True)` which lists all files recursively.

I could do it by entering manually each dir, and then redo a `msld()` but I fear this will be very slow (listing files in FTP is already slow as far as I remember), so this is not optimal.

How would one do it with SFTP? Would it be easier with SFTP to list all files recursively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I could do it by entering manually each dir, and then redo a msld()

And that's the correct solution. FTP protocol does not have any better *standard* way to retrieve recursive listing. So there's no space for optimization (only by parallelizing the operation). See also [Downloading a directory tree with ftplib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2605119/850848).

Some FTP servers support non-standard `-R` switch with some file listing commands (not sure about `MLSD`). So if you are willing to rely on a non-standard functionality and your particular server supports it, you can optimize your code this way. See also [Getting all FTP directory/file listings recursively in one call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50438785/850848).

For SFTP, see [Recursive SFTP listdir in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48368690/850848)

Answer (score 2):

As `LIST -R`, `NLST -R`, `MLSD -R` were not working for me, I following @MartinPrikryl's recommendation and here is a FTP solution:

```
import ftplib, time
def list_recursive(ftp, remotedir):
    ftp.cwd(remotedir)
    for entry in ftp.mlsd():
        if entry[1]['type'] == 'dir':
            remotepath = remotedir + "/" + entry[0]
            print(time.time() - t0, remotepath)
            list_recursive(ftp, remotepath)
        else:
            print(entry)
ftp = ftplib.FTP()
ftp.connect("192.168.1.18", port=2240)
ftp.login()
t0 = time.time()
list_recursive(ftp, '/sdcard/music')
```

It took 344 seconds for ~20k files in ~900 folders (my FTP server is on a phone: cx File Explorer app).

---

As a comparison, here is a solution for SFTP:

```
import pysftp
def list_recursive(sftp, remotedir):
    for entry in sftp.listdir_attr(remotedir):
        remotepath = remotedir + "/" + entry.filename
        if sftp.isdir(remotepath):
            print(remotepath)            
            list_recursive(sftp, remotepath)
        else:
            print(entry.st_size, entry.st_mtime, entry.filename)
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()  # for local testing
cnopts.hostkeys = None 
with pysftp.Connection('192.168.1.18', port=2222, username='ssh', password='', cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
    list_recursive(sftp, 'music')
```

It took 222 seconds for ~20k files in ~900 folders (I used SSH/SFTP Server app on an Android phone).

Comment: +1 – Though one obligatory warning: Do not set `cnopts.hostkeys = None`, unless you do not care about security. See [Verify host key with pysftp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38939454/850848).