# pysftp's conn.stat("path/to/file") doesn't raise error if file is not present

Tags: python, sftp, pysftp

Sometimes I need to iterate through the files in a folder with `pysftp` and I want to retrieve information for the files matching with my fnmatch_pattern (refer to [fnmatch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html)). I would like that the function `conn.stat("path")` raised an error in case the file wasn't present.

Reproducible example below:

```py
   def get_mod_time_pattern(self, dir_path: str, fnmatch_pattern: str = None) -> Dict[str, str]:
        d = {}
        conn = pysftp.Connection(**my_conn_paramt)
        
        # file list of files respecting matches
        flist = [file for file in conn.listdir(dir_path) if fnmatch(file, fnmatch_pattern)]

        for file in flist:
            path_to_file = os.path.join(dir_path, file)
            d[path_to_file] = conn.stat(path_to_file).st_mtime

    return d
```

with this solution - where flist is empty - the function `conn.stat` doesn't raise the usual `IOError` that is normally raised when the file is not existing.
How can I make it raising the error? Thanks

Comment: When `flist` is empty, your code will never even call the `conn.stat`. + Your code is wrong anyway.  If you want file details, use `listdir_attr` – See https://stackoverflow.com/q/12295551/850848#57694519

Comment: yes, it did. I need to find a way in which `conn.stat` is called; thanks!