# Paramiko Python. How can i get the last modified file on the SFTP?

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

I need to get the last modified file's name using paramiko

```
client.connect(hostname=server["host"], username=server["user"], pkey=pkey, allow_agent=False, look_for_keys=False)
    
sftp = client.open_sftp()
print("Connected!")
```

I don't know how to proceed from here!

I tried:

```
utime = sftp.stat("path").st_mtime
last_modified = datetime.fromtimestamp(utime)

print(last_modified)
```

someone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the list of files in `'path'` and find the one with the greatest modified time:

```py
last_modified = max(
    sftp.listdir_attr('path'),
    key=lambda f.st_mtime
)
print(last_modified.filename)
```

**edit:** Changed `listdir()/stat()` to `listdir_attr()` because it's more efficient. According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57694519/4583620) `listdir()` calls `listdir_attr()` and throws away everything but the filename.

---

If you need to filter out the directories:

```py
from stat import S_ISREG
last_modified = max(
    filter(lambda f: S_ISREG(f.st_mode), sftp.listdir_attr('path')),
    key=lambda f: f.st_mtime
)
print(last_modified.filename)
```