# Getting tree structure of directories

Tags: python, file

I was trying to use the code given in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727673/list-directory-tree-structure-using-python/9728478#9728478). However, I don't understand what the line

```
level = root.replace(startpath, '').count(os.sep)
```

is supposed to do.

Also, when I ran the code, it gave an error `ValueError: zero length field name in format` on the line

```
print('{}{}/'.format(indent, os.path.basename(root)))
```

Comment: You're using Python 2.6 or lower, so replace `{}{}` with `{0}{1}`. Also, if you're using Windows, there's the `tree` command. You can install one for *nix as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`level = root.replace(startpath, '').count(os.sep)`

It's calculating level of indentation for printing object (dir/file) name. It's getting rid of startpath as it's common for every listed file and it would look bad to have everything indented by +10 tabs :) os.sep returns path separator like '/' on Linux.

About that error, try: 
`print('{0}{1}/'.format(indent, os.path.basename(root)))`
There you have some examples: http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples Probably your Python is not 2.7+

Comment: I was writing the same answer (even with the same link) but you were faster / byłeś szybszy ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
root.replace(startpath, '').count(os.sep)
```

The `root` is the current directory of the walk.

```
root.replace(startpath, '')
```

removes the `startpath` from the `root` to get the path relative to the startpath.

```
root.replace(startpath, '').count(os.sep)
```

counts the number of `os.sep`s, for example `/` for Linux, within this relative path. This count is the depth of the current directory relative to the startpath.