# Creating a textual summary at the end of an operation

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need your help. I created a Python 2.7 script that moves some files around. Now, what I want to do is a "summary" at the end of the program, stating what files were moved and where. This summary though, must be somehow with an "identation". Let me show you what I mean:

```
- Folder A
    |
    |------- File 1
    |------- File 2
    |------- File 3

-Folder B
    |
    |------- Sub Folder B1
                    |
                    |-------- File 1
                    |-------- File 2
                    |---------File X..
```

How can I achieve something like this in python?

Thank you so much!

EDIT:

Ok, here is the solution:

```
import os

def list_files(startpath):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(startpath):
        level = root.replace(startpath, '').count(os.sep)
        indent = ' ' * 4 * (level)
        print('{}{}/'.format(indent, os.path.basename(root)))
        subindent = ' ' * 4 * (level + 1)
        for f in files:
            print('{}{}'.format(subindent, f))
```

Thank you!

Comment: Possible dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727673/list-directory-tree-structure-using-python

Answer (score 1):

There is a script on [Active State Recipes](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/217212-treepy-graphically-displays-the-directory-structur/) which does exactly that:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

# tree.py
#
# Written by Doug Dahms
#
# Prints the tree structure for the path specified on the command line

from os import listdir, sep
from os.path import abspath, basename, isdir
from sys import argv

def tree(dir, padding, print_files=False):
    print padding[:-1] + '+-' + basename(abspath(dir)) + '/'
    padding = padding + ' '
    files = []
    if print_files:
        files = listdir(dir)
    else:
        files = [x for x in listdir(dir) if isdir(dir + sep + x)]
    count = 0
    for file in files:
        count += 1
        print padding + '|'
        path = dir + sep + file
        if isdir(path):
            if count == len(files):
                tree(path, padding + ' ', print_files)
            else:
                tree(path, padding + '|', print_files)
        else:
            print padding + '+-' + file

def usage():
    return '''Usage: %s [-f] <PATH>
Print tree structure of path specified.
Options:
-f      Print files as well as directories
PATH    Path to process''' % basename(argv[0])

def main():
    if len(argv) == 1:
        print usage()
    elif len(argv) == 2:
        # print just directories
        path = argv[1]
        if isdir(path):
            tree(path, ' ')
        else:
            print 'ERROR: \'' + path + '\' is not a directory'
    elif len(argv) == 3 and argv[1] == '-f':
        # print directories and files
        path = argv[2]
        if isdir(path):
            tree(path, ' ', True)
        else:
            print 'ERROR: \'' + path + '\' is not a directory'
    else:
        print usage()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This is overkill for what I have in mind :) Thank you anyway!