# Python move "met conditional value" outside of loop

Tags: python, replace, conditional-statements, placeholder, substitution

This may be confusing.

```
rootdir= C:\User\Desktop\File
file = 'file.txt'

mainLocNum = str(list(rootdir)).count(r'\\')
mainFolder=os.listdir(rootdir)

with open(file,'w') as f:

    for dir, subdirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        currentDirLevel=str(list(dir)).count(r'\\')
        for allFolders in subdirs:
            if (currentDirLevel - mainLocNum) == 0:
                parentFolders=allFolders
                f.write(str(parentFolders))
                PLACEHOLDER
            elif (currentDirLevel - mainLocNum) == 1:
                subFolders=allFolders
                f.write(str(allFolders)     <----- write this in PLACEHOLDER
```

I want to write the second `write` statement into the `PLACEHOLDER` line only if the `elif` condition is met.  If I don't write the second `write` statement in the `PLACEHOLDER` position, the second `write` statement in the second conditional is written at the very bottom of the text file; however I want to write the second conditional's `write` statement (only if it is met) in the `PLACEHOLDER` position, which is in between each of the first `write` iterations.

I've been trying different nesting methods, but I am lacking in fundamental loop construction logic.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

EDIT:

I am looping through a main directory, and I am writing all of the parent folders into the text file. I want to write in between each parent folder its subfolders: i.e if the parent folder contains more folders, to write those folders in between each parent folder; and if the parent folder does not contain any more folders, to skip to the next parent folder etc. I am using the if (currentDirLevel - mainLocNum)==(number) to know how many directories it is stepping into and to perform a different write function for each step.

I am trying to write the names of the folders in certain formats depending on whether they are level 1 sub-directories, level 2 sub-directories etc...

What I want:

```
ParentFolder1
    SubFolder1
    Subfolder2
        SubSubFolder1
    SubFolder3
ParentFolder2
    SubFolder1
ParentFolder3
ParentFolder4
    SubFolder1
        SubSubFolder1
            SubSubSubFolder1
        SubSubFolder2
    SubFolder2
ParentFolder5
    SubFolder1
```

What I am getting

```
ParentFolder1
ParentFolder2
ParentFolder3
ParentFolder4
ParentFolder5
SubFolder1
SubFolder2
SubFolder3
SubFolder1
SubFolder1
SubFolder2
SubFolder1
SubSubFolder1
SubSubFolder1
SubSubFolder2
SubSubSubFolder1
```

Please don't focus on the os.walk or iterating through the directories.  I have a lot of code written already, and I want the main focus to answer my question about running a conditional loop and placing the value within that loop into a write function inside another loop.

I would prefer restructuring this loop logic rather than starting over with the whole os.walk for loop.

Thanks again

Comment: you cant iterate through a file if its opened with `'w'`

Comment: Thanks, I will edit the question.  I rushed into simplifying my situation.

Comment: Are you trying to write a script that opens itself and rewrites its own code? Does "file" refer to this file? Or some other file?

Comment: So you only want `f.write(i+command2)` to run if `x == certain_value`?

Comment: I put a lot more detail into what is going on.  I hope this clarifies things a bit.

Comment: Make sure you post something that "works" as in, shows your error if I were (hypothetically) to run it myself. That means I also need some data that you are using, and to know what the output is that you are expecting but not getting.

Comment: Can you describe in words *exactly* what you want your program to do?

Comment: OK, I will try my best.  I am looping through a main directory, and I am writing all of the parent folders in the text file.  I want to write in between each parent folder its subfolders, i.e if the parent folder contains more folders, to write those folders in between each parent folder; and if the parent folder does not contain any more folders, to skip to the next parent folder etc.  I am using the if (currentDirLevel - mainLocNum)==(number) to know how many directories it is stepping into and to perform a different write function for each step.

Comment: Add this description into the question. by "writing" you mean like "printing"?

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question.  Yes, I am trying to write the names of the folders in certain formats depending on whether they are level 1 sub-directories, level 2 sub-directories etc...

Comment: A fairly fundamental problem you have with using os.walk() is that it doesn't go depth-first which is what you need. os.walk() goes width-first - it gives you all the folders at the current level before going into the subfolders.

Comment: Never forget goggle is your friend. A quick search turns up this - the expected answer is what you want, I think. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727673/list-directory-tree-structure-using-python

Comment: oops, "accepted answer"

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping someone would explain how to work with the 'if' conditionals and running the command from the conditional block into another loop (the whole "PLACEHOLDER" thing).  I didn't want an answer leading me on to re-write and re-think the os.walk loop logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by the term "conditional loop", but what you're trying to achieve is easily done using a small recursive function based on `os.listdir`. You *could* do this using `os.walk`, but I often find it simpler (and more efficient) to call `os.listdir` explicitly (`os.walk` calls `os.listdir` internally), especially when you don't need separate lists of directories and plain files.

```
import os

tab = 4 * ' '

def writedirs(fhandle, path, depth=0):
    ''' Recursively walk the directory tree starting at path,
        writing all directory names to open file handle fhandle.
        Nodes are traversed depth-first, top-down, and names
        are indented proportional to their depth.
    '''
    data = os.listdir(path)
    # Names returned by listdir are in file system order;
    # If you want them sorted alphabetically, call
    # data.sort()
    # or
    # data.sort(key=str.lower)
    # for case-insensitive sorting.

    indent = depth * tab
    depth += 1
    for filename in data:
        fullpath = os.path.join(path, filename)
        if os.path.isdir(fullpath):
            fhandle.write(indent + filename + '\n')
            writedirs(fhandle, fullpath, depth)

#Test
rootdir = 'testfolder'
outname = 'file.txt'
with open(outname, 'w') as fhandle:
    writedirs(fhandle, rootdir)
```

**contents of 'file.txt'**

```
ParentFolder1
    SubFolder1
    Subfolder2
        SubSubFolder1
    SubFolder3
ParentFolder2
    SubFolder1
ParentFolder3
ParentFolder4
    SubFolder1
        SubSubFolder1
            SubSubSubFolder1
        SubSubFolder2
    SubFolder2
ParentFolder5
    SubFolder1
```

It's generally better to avoid recursion in Python, when practical: the Python interpreter cannot perform [tail call elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), and it imposes a maximum recursion depth. However, when dealing with recursive data structures (like file trees) it's natural to use a recursive algorithm.

---

FWIW, the code below iteratively performs the inverse operation of the code above; I used it to build the directory tree from the indented list of directory names given in the question.

```
import os

data = '''
ParentFolder1
    SubFolder1
    Subfolder2
        SubSubFolder1
    SubFolder3
ParentFolder2
    SubFolder1
ParentFolder3
ParentFolder4
    SubFolder1
        SubSubFolder1
            SubSubSubFolder1
        SubSubFolder2
    SubFolder2
ParentFolder5
    SubFolder1
'''[1:]

def show(seq):
    for row in seq:
        print(row)
    print()

def stripcount(s):
    z = s.lstrip(' ')
    count = len(s) - len(z)
    return z, count

joinpath = os.path.join

def make_dir_tree(dir_tree, root=''):
    ''' Create a directory tree in root from dir_tree,
        which is a list of indented directory names.
    '''
    dir_tree = [stripcount(s) for s in dir_tree]
    #show(dir_tree)

    stack = [root]
    depth = -1
    for dname, count in dir_tree:
        if count > depth:
            depth = count
            stack.append(dname)
        elif count < depth:
            depth = count
            stack.pop()
            stack[-1] = dname
        else:
            stack[-1] = dname

        pathname = joinpath(*stack)
        print(pathname)
        os.mkdir(pathname)


dir_tree = data.splitlines()
show(dir_tree)
make_dir_tree(dir_tree, 'testfolder')
```

Comment: Thank you for putting all that time and effort into answering my question.  I'll give it a shot.  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @MikeIssa: My pleasure! To be honest, I was more intrigued by the inverse problem. :) That code for creating directory trees might come in handy...

Comment: Yes, that was an interesting thing you did there.  Creating, or reverse engineering directory paths out of a directory tree of text.  Cool stuff...  Respect!