# Show directory structure of a Python project?

Tags: tree, operating-system, directory, directory-structure

I want to show structure of python project like this.

can I uses some commend like `python manage.py [something]`...?

```
ROOT
├── lib
│   ├── django
│   ├── pytz
│   ├── wanttousing_lib
│   └── ...
├── mysite
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── controllers.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── views.py
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── like
│   │        ├── index.html
│   │        └── _likehelpers.html
│   └── ....
├── test
│   ├── like
│   │   ├── models_tests.py
│   │   └── controllers_tests.py
│   └── ....
├── static
│   ├── css
│   └── js
├── app.yaml
├── manage.py
├── appengine_config.py
└── requirements.txt
```

Comment: Do you want to show it in the command line? What OS are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List directory tree structure in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727673/list-directory-tree-structure-in-python)

Comment: Thank you all !!! it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In the Windows command prompt**

```
cd path/to/ROOT
tree /f
```

or if you want to export this tree to a file, use this command

```
tree /f > tree.txt
```

then open tree.txt

**In Linux/MacOS terminal**

First, you should install package name `tree`

- In MacOS: `brew install tree`
- In RHEL/CentOS/Fedora: `yum install tree`
- In Debian/Mint/Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install tree`

Then run this command:

```
tree /path/to/ROOT
```

Comment: Well, that's not Python

Answer (score 0):

There is a command line tool named `tree` in Linux & Mac OS. You can install it with package manager.

```
brew install tree  # for mac os
yum install tree # for centos

cd path/to/ROOT
tree . -I "regex_of_ignored_files_and_dirs" -o outputfilename
```

Or you can modify the manager.py to call this command in it.

Answer (score 0):

[`exa`](https://the.exa.website/) can do this. You can find installation instructions [here](https://the.exa.website/#installation). However, on macOS, it's just:

```
brew install exa
```

The command looks like this:

```
exa -T my_stuff

my_stuff
├── file1.txt
├── file2.csv
├── file3.py
└── more_stuff
   └── file3.pyc
```

or

```
cd /to/your/folder
exa -T

.
├── file1.txt
├── file2.csv
├── file3.py
└── more_stuff
   └── file3.pyc
```

Comment: I believe the author wants to show the structure of a Python project but is not confining solutions to use only Python