# Parse text (or ASCII) directory tree to Python object

Tags: python, tree, filesystems

This is more or less reverse question to [List directory tree structure in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727673/list-directory-tree-structure-in-python) and this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51991554/7422721

Given that we have text art style directory tree (ASCII, but not limited to), generated as an output from `tree` program or equivalent Python script:

```
a/
├── b/
│   └── c/
│       ├── file_1
│       └── file_2
└── d/
```

Each file name ends with one of the `'/', '=', '*', '@', '|' or '>'` indicating file type, as with the `ls -F` or `tree -F` convention. So file name ending with `/` would be directory, `=` for socket etc. If there is no ending, we assume that it is regular file.

How can I read this back into native data structure, for example:

```
[
  "a": [
    "b": [
      "c": [
        "file_1", "file_2"
      ]
    ],
    "d": []
  ]
]
```

Or to other object that could represent in memory filesystem?

Goal here would be to create readable unit tests for script that manipulates files on disk.

Comment: So you want to convert ASCII tree to dict?

Comment: @Alderven This is a bit specific - I want to convert text tree to Python object. It does not necessarily have to be nested list/dict, but I think it would be the simplest one to impement.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to convert sample tree from your question to dict format:

```
{'a': {'b': {'c': {'file_1': {}, 'file_2': {}}}, 'd': {}}}
```

Script:

```
import re

def find_children(tree):
    result = {}
    for i, line in enumerate(tree.split('\n')):
        child = re.findall('^\w+', line)
        if child:
            parent = child[0]
            child_tree = '\n'.join([x[len(parent)+3:] for x in tree.split('\n')[i+1:]])
            result[parent] = find_children(child_tree)
    return result

with open('tree.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    tree_dict = find_children(f.read())
```

Comment: I like the idea of ignoring special characters like `├ └ │ ─`. But it will fail on anything little more complicated than the provided sample with a,b,c.... Try for example using it on the output of `tree /etc` :)